# using RC4 in Openssl on Ubuntu instead of Camellia

Tags: ubuntu, encryption, openssl

I've got a very basic problem:

I managed to run Openssl on my Server with a self-signed cert and Camellia 256-bit encryption.
When I look up on Google / Facebook etc. encryption, they all use RC4 128-bit which makes sense cause its much faster.
Now my question is, how can I change the encryption to RC4, I looked it up all over the place but only found stuff to de/encrypt single files, not the private and public keys.

Thanks for help in advance,

Eric

Comment: This is for SSL? Simply explicitly set the desired ciphersuites with, for example, [SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list](http://openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list.html#)

Comment: thank you for your help, but I don't know how to use your command. It even says command not found. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were writing a C/C++ program that uses the openssl library. In fact you are actually do something else. So are you using `openssl s_server`? Or are you using the apache server?

Comment: sorry for the late answer, I am using lighttpd atm in cgi mode

Answer (score 0):

Since the cert is self-signed, it presumably didn't cost anything. So, can't you just create a new cert using `openssl` but with the desired cipher suite?

Comment: Certs don't have ciphersuites, so the answer doesn't make sense.